# Why is the following command killing a system?

Tags: bash, process, limit, fork

Anyone understand the following code , running in bash ?

`:(){ :|:& };:`

It seems to be a "`fork`" bomb on Linux.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not that difficult to decipher in fact.

This piece of code just defines a function named `:` which calls two instances of itself in a pipeline: `:|:&`. After the definition an instance of this function is started.

This leads to a fast increasing number of subshell processes. Unprotected systems (systems without a process number limit per user) will be severely affected by such fork bombs since legitimate processes will quickly be outnumbered and thus deprived of most CPU resources.

Comment: Which OS is not protected against this?